# O que é e com que se faz com cada um desses SHA-1, SHA-256, HASH, MD5 no dia a dia?

Tags: java, terminologia, hash

O que é e o que se faz com cada um desses SHA-1, SHA-256, HASH, MD5 no dia a dia?

Comment: São algoritmos de _hash_.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/18246) — [É eficiente verificar modificações de arquivos por Hash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20929/18246) — [O hash do MD5 pode se repetir para senhas diferentes causando colisão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99194/18246) — [O que é e para que serve um checksum?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115905/18246)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: [Qual a diferença entre codificação, criptografia e cálculo hash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162369/18246)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: [Como funcionam o algoritmos de hash da família SHA?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43493/18246)

Comment: ola, estou lendo todos os links, muito obrigado, por favor, qual a relação de hash com Base64?

Comment: @DouglasMaogrande Um hash tipicamente é uma sequência de bytes com aspecto caótico. Se você tentar tratá-lo como string, ele poderá ter caracteres não-imprimíveis, caracteres invisíveis e caracteres que não foram mapeados no padrão unicode. Assim sendo, usa-se o Base64 ou o hexadecimal para deixá-lo em um formato uniforme e simples onde todos os caracteres são imprimíveis e dentro de um conjunto bem delimitado.

Comment: após lido todos os comentário ficou claro que pra proteger senha o melhor é o BEncript, certo ? por favor, qual biblioteca usar ele? Não tem no java, ne?

Comment: @DouglasMaogrande https://howtodoinjava.com/security/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/

Comment: Victor, muito obrigado pela grande ajuda... Voce poderia me dizer o que é unicode e hexadecimal , por favor?